# I am trying to extract only date value from Oracle's SYSDATE but my query is giving me ORA-02290: check constraint violated

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, check-constraint

I want to insert current date into my record, First I executed this query successfully.

```
insert into Member values (1, 'Richa Sharma', 'Pune', TO_DATE('10-Dec-05', 'DD-MM-YY'), 'Lifetime', '25000', 5, 50);
```

Then while executing the following query I'm getting the above error code.

```
insert into Member values (2, 'Garima Sen', 'Pune', SYSDATE, 'Annual', 100, 3, NULL);
```

EDIT: This is the query I used to create table.

```
create table Member (Member_Id number(5), 
Member_Name varchar2(30), 
Member_Address varchar2(50), 
Acc_Open_Date date, 
Membership_Type varchar2(20), 
Fees_Paid number(6), 
Max_Books_Allowed number(2), 
Penalty_Amount number(7,2),
PRIMARY KEY(Member_Id),
CHECK (Membership_Type IN ('Lifetime',' Annual', 'Half Yearly',' Quarterly')));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your check constraint has a leading space in `' Annual'` change to `'Annual'`

Comment: omg, so silly of me, all this time I thought the error is coming because of SYSDATE. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome Luffy, things like this happens to everybody, glad to help. and BTW just noticed `Quarterly` has also a leading space, be sure to fix that.